# Vagrant: disconnect NAT from internet on adapter 1 after ssh login

Tags: networking, vagrant

According to [1](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/5708), NAT on adapter 1 is a hard requirement of Vagrant, otherwise you may encounter ssh problem when `vagrant ssh`.

Here is what I want: I have a Whonix Gateway installed providing Tor service. The Whonix Gateway stays in a internal network of Virtualbox. And I have a Debian installed via Vagrant. I attached Debian to the internal network of Whonix Gateway on adapter 2 so that it could forward traffic to Tor. Since the default NAT on adapter 1 connects to internet, it is possible that some traffic leaks(not routed by Tor network).

It is possible that I could configure Vagrant to disable internet connection on adapter 1? Or you may have other advice to achieve my goal?

Comment: Hi @JACK, did you find any workaround to do this?

Comment: @another, sadly, no

Comment: All right @JACK